# How to do mocking with Moq without exposing interfaces to users?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class Context {
  public void initialize() { ... }
}
```

and another class using it:

```
public class Service {
  public Context getContext() { return context; }

  internal Service(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    context.initialize();
  }

  private Context context;
}
```

Finally, let say I want to write a unit test for `Service` that verifies that `Context.initalize` is called upon class construction. Since it's a unit test, I would want to mock `Context` instead of using a real class. With Moq that requires creating an interface `IContext` and rewriting the code as following:

```
public interface IContext {
  void initialize();
}

public class Context : IContext {
  public void initialize() { ... }
}

public class Service {
  public IContext getContext() { return context; }

  internal Service(IContext ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    context.initialize();
  }

  private IContext context;
}

[TestFixture()]
public class ServiceTest {
  [Test()]
  public shouldInitializeContextWhenConstructed() {
    Mock<IContext> mockContext = new Mock<IContext>();
    Service service = new Service(mockContext);
    mockContext.Verify(c => c.initialize(), Times.Once());
  }
}
```

However, since `IContext` is purely test-related artifact, I would like to avoid exposing it to the users of the `Service` class (via `Service.getContext` function). What would be the correct solution here?

Comment: An alternative to introducing the interface is marking the method `initialize` as `virtual`. That should be enough to make Moq able to mock the method. Of course that trades one "problem" (the introduction of an unwanted interface) for another (making a method virtual which means people (other than Moq) could derive from the class and override the method).

Comment: Another thing is you can change `public interface IContext` to `internal interface IContext`. It looks like your test fixture class is in the same assembly (since the constructor is accessible), otherwise the test assembly would need to be a friend assembly (`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`). If the "users" of the `Service` class are in other assemblies, you have hidden the interface for them.

Comment: When I make the interface internal, then IDE will complain that it's not public and thus not accessible to the Moq assemblies. Using `virtual` modifier may be a solution. I didn't know that Moq supports this. Will try it out...

Comment: Moq is based on Castle.DynamicProxy, so it's possible to make internal interface visible to it with attribute: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]`

Comment: @JurySoldatenkov Good info. I had forgotten that.

Comment: But why? If you don't want callers to get their dirty paws on your context (in which case, why do you need getContext, you don't need it for tests as you have already shown with the Mock verification) and letting a caller see that Context is an IContext is pure semantics - all they can see is that this object implements this contract, and so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to mark `IContext` as `internal` and use `as` operator to cast `context` to `Context`. This is safe, because actual `context` will always be `Context` when used by the users:

```
internal interface IContext {
    void initialize();
}

public class Context : IContext {
    public void initialize() { }
}

public class ServiceFactory {
    public static Service createService() { return new Service(new Context()); }
}

public class Service {
    public Context getContext() { return context as Context; }

    internal Service(IContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        context.initialize();
    }

    private IContext context;
}

[TestFixture()]
public class ServiceTest {

    [Test()]
    public void shouldInitializeContextWhenConstructed() {
        Mock<IContext> mockContext = new Mock<IContext>();
        new Service(mockContext.Object);
        mockContext.Verify(c => c.initialize(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```